# ind equivalent expression: $\sum_1^nk^2*2^{-k}$

Tags: calculus

I need to find an equivalent expression (,but without the sigma notation and using 'n' as a variable) of the expression: $\sum_1^nk^2*2^{-k}$

Comment: What you wrote is not an equation, and so it cannot be solved.  Did you mean to say you need to evaluate the expression?

Comment: I just want to obtain an equivalent formula, but without the sigma notation. (i.e. with n as a variable)

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* that your summation is over $k$,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^nk^2*2^{-k} = 1^2\cdot2^{-1} + 2^2\cdot2^{-2} + 3^2\cdot2^{-3} + \cdots + n^2 \cdot 2^{-n}
\end{equation}

This is an equivalent expression without sigma notation.

Answer (score 0):

an equivalent expression is:
$2^{-n} (-6 + 3\cdot2^{1+n}-4 n-n^2)$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. Please, could you explain how you got the expression or give me a website address where it is explained?